# How do I use the page number that is the index of the pdf itself to goto a location with Acrobat Reader?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm using Acrobat Reader 20.13 on my mac.

Acrobat Reader allows me to input the page number that printed on the book, pointed out by the red arrow to goto a location.

How do I use the page number that is the index of the pdf itself, pointed out by the blue arrow to goto a location?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

- Go to Acrobat Reader menu
  *Edit > Preferences > Page Display*
- Uncheck the option of "Use Logical Page Numbers"
- Click OK.

When this option is unchecked the absolute page number is displayed,
and when it is checked you'll get something like "Cover (1 of 88)" showing up.

The effect of the change is immediate - no need to restart Acrobat Reader.

Answer (score 1):

This works on Windows and might also work on Mac. Type the page, for example (based on the image provided on the OP) `66 of 1438`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will send you to page 51. You can also type `66 of` to accomplish the same thing.